# Permutation Haskell

Tags: haskell, permutation

I have a Haskell work which ask me to write a permutation function using 2 other functions prepend and delete I wrote before, those two functions works fine but I somehow don't know how to connect those 2 into the perm function, how can i do this?

```
prepend :: Num a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
prepend a l = map (a :) l

delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete x [] = []
delete x (y:ys) 
    | x == y    = delete x ys
    | otherwise = y : delete x ys
```

The declaration of perm should be : `perm :: Num a ⇒ [a] → [[a]]`

What I tried:

```
perm [] = [[]]
perm p = [prepend x xs |  x <- p, xs <- perm (delete x p)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `:` instead of `prepend`.

```
perm p = [x:xs | ...]
```

Comment: So, don't use prepend?  Won't that fail to meet the requirements of the assignment?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe? It's very hard to know whether writing `prepend` was meant as a hint or a requirement. I certainly don't think the version that uses `prepend` is much simpler.

Comment: I think its a requiement cause this form perm p = [x:xs | ...] doesn't meet the declaration which i forgot to mention : perm :: Num a ⇒ [a] → [[a]]. Do you other advice? Thanks

Comment: @鶫月海 It works with the declaration `perm :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [[a]]`. If you plan to call `delete`, you cannot avoid the `Eq` constraint, because `delete` has it. If you must avoid `Eq`, you will have to modify the way `delete` works (and, presumably, the way `delete` is called).

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Yeah i find that stange too... maybe its a mistake in topic, but thanks for your advice anyway

Comment: I managed to make it works, if u are intrested: perm :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
perm [] = [[]]
perm p = [y | x<-p, y <-prepend x (perm (delete x p))]